# Was Zhivkov under house arrest partly for inciting racial hatred?

Tags: communism, bulgaria

So I was randomly reading about Tohor Zhivkov. The [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/1999/mar/10/1) states:

> Zhivkov, who has since died, was tried and sentenced to house
> imprisonment, partly for inciting racial hatred in a 1980s campaign to
> make the Turkish-origin community change their names to 'Bulgarian'
> ones.

On the other hand [Wikipedia:TodorZhivkov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todor_Zhivkov) states:

> Following his fall from power, the new regime brought Zhivkov to five
> separate trials - labelled trials No.1 through No. 5 of the Republic
> of Bulgaria, each with their own indictment. Indictment No. 1 regarded
> the 'Revival Process', Indictment 2 accused him of overstepping his
> authority in "funding the international communist movement",
> Indictment 3 accused him and 21 others of giving out high-risk loans
> to developing countries, Indictment 4 accused him of giving away
> apartments and cars worth a total of around $24 million (in 1990
> dollars) to members of the security forces and indictment 5 accused
> him of involvement in labour camps. The first four were brought before
> the court immediately, while as indictment 5 was brought before the
> court later
>
> Zhivkov pled not guilty to all counts on all indictments, but was
> initially found guilty of one of the four indictments at that point,
> Indictment 4, and was subsequently sentenced to seven years in prison.
> He disputed the court's verdict and appealed it. An appellate court
> found "oddities" in the original verdict and decided to confirm it,
> but lowered his sentence to just 1 year and 6 months.

What is historically accurate? Was Zhivkov under house arrest   partly for inciting racial hatred? Is there some good online resource where I can read on this person?

Comment: The racial hatred part seems to be about the Revival Project. If the wp article is correct, it means he was tried, but not sentenced for inciting racial hatred

Comment: "Racial hatred" is a poor translation . More like forced Bulgarisation and expulsion of Turks from Bulgaria.